# Interpreting the answer to a simple probability question

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

I come across this simple problem, which I paraphrase slightly from its original wording:

> A spellchecker has checked $200$ pages. Only $12$ of them contain no typos: the rest all had at least $1$ typo. Altogether in the $200$ pages, about how many typos are there?

The given answer just has a few computations:
$$
e^{-\lambda}\approx\frac{12}{200}=0.06\implies \lambda\approx 2.8134\implies\text{total}\approx 2.8134\times 200\approx 563.
$$
The first implication is just algebra but I don't know why the solution starts by setting $e^{-\lambda}=\frac{12}{200}$.

I think the problem is worded not very rigorously but since it comes from a course which I'm not attending, maybe there has been some context already given in class that I don't have access to.

Can you please explain the solution or give a different one if it is wrong?

Comment: This smells like Poisson approximation to binomial distribution.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri If you convert that into an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They model it using Poisson distribution.

$$P(X=x) = \exp(-\lambda) \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

$$P(X=0) = \exp(-\lambda) \frac{\lambda^0}{0!}=\exp(-\lambda)$$